# How to find/remove item by certain condition in SortedList?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code in my `class OutlookItemsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<OutlookItemsViewHolder>()`:

```
companion object {
    lateinit var outlookItems: SortedList<OutlookItem>
}

init {
    outlookItems = SortedList(OutlookItem::class.java, object: SortedListAdapterCallback<OutlookItem>(this){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(item1: OutlookItem, item2: OutlookItem): Boolean = item1 == item2

        override fun compare(o1: OutlookItem, o2: OutlookItem): Int = o1.DateTime.compareTo(o2.DateTime)

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: OutlookItem, newItem: OutlookItem): Boolean = oldItem.EntryId.equals(newItem.EntryId)
    })
}
```

Where `OutlookItem` is:

```
class OutlookItem (
    val Subject: String,
    val EntryId: String,
    val DateTime: LocalDateTime,
    val MeetingUrl: String?
)
```

I need to write a function that receives an `EntryId` and deletes its equivalent `OutlookItem` from the list. Unfortunately `SortedList` doesn't have this capability (i.e. find/remove element determined by e.g. some lambda).

Is there an easy way to accomplish that or do I actually need to implement this finding mechanism on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SortedList doesn't actually implement the List interface, you can't use any of Kotlin's helper higher-order functions for Lists on it.

A finding higher-order function can be written like this:

```
inline fun <T> SortedList<T>.firstOrNull(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
    for (index in 0 until size()){
        this[index].let { 
            if (predicate(it)) return it
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Then you could use this to perform your described task like this:

```
fun SortedList<OutlookItem>.removeByEntryId(entryId: String) {
    val item = firstOrNull { it.EntryId == entryId }
    if (item != null) remove(item)
}
```

By the way, by convention, property names should always start with a lower-case letter unless they are constants (in which case they are all caps).